# How to support svelte code rendered from an exported svelte component to DOM

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to call a svelte component from one SvelteKit App to another so I can render it in caller App's DOM.
I've created an endpoint that fetches the component, renders it and sends the response to the caller as shown below:

```js
export async function get({ query, page }) {
    const ASSET = (await import("../../assets/myasset.svelte")).default;

    if (ASSET) {
        let renderedAsset = ASSET.render();
        return {
            body: { asset: renderedAsset }
        };
    } else {
        return {
            status: data.status,
            error: new Error(`Could not load ${response}`)
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the component:

```html
<svelte:head>
    <script>
        let div = document.querySelector('.my-class');
        div.addEventListener('click', function () {
            window.alert('IT Works');
        });
    </script>
</svelte:head>
<h1 class="my-class">HELLO</h1>

<style>
    h1 {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

I get this object on the caller side:

```
{
    "asset": {
        "html": "\n<h1 class=\"my-class s-ZmOKpGJa32Cj\">HELLO</h1>",
        "css": {
            "code": "h1.s-ZmOKpGJa32Cj{color:blue}.s-ZmOKpGJa32Cj{}",
            "map": null
        },
        "head": "<script class=\"s-ZmOKpGJa32Cj\" data-svelte=\"svelte-muoug1\">let div = document.querySelector('.my-class');\n        div.addEventListener('click', function () {\n            window.alert('IT Works');\n        });\n    </script>"
    }
}
```

I'm injecting this in the caller's DOM like this:

```html
{@html `<${''}style>${Final.asset.css.code }</${''}style>` }

{@html Final.asset.html}
{@html Final.asset.head}
```

This works fine, but when I use svelte's functionality like this:

```html
<svelte:head>
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(() => {
        let div = document.querySelector('.my-class');
        div.addEventListener('click', function () {
            window.alert('IT Works');
        });
    });
</script>
</svelte:head>
<h1 class="my-class">HELLO </h1>
<style>
h1 {
color: blue;
}
</style>
```

It throws error saying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.
How can I use svelte's functionality(svelte code/in-built functions/ hydration part) and export it to be used by another App?

Comment: I guess you are using rollup bundler for your app but this one doesn't handle the mix between modules and common js. The solution would be to use the app template with webpack that handle both.

Comment: @johannchopin SvelteKit uses Vite for bundling. Not sure if I can use app template with webpack. Can you give an example?